# How to check in a JSP if it is receiving a photo?

Tags: jsp

I would like to show an objects photo ONLY when there is one in my JSP. I'm using this code and it shows no photo even when there is one...

```
<c:if test="empty ${contextRoot}/statusphoto/${statusUpdate.photo.id}">  
        <img class="img-responsive full-width" src="${contextRoot}/statusphoto/${statusUpdate.photo.id}" alt=""/>
</c:if>
```

I can not find any other way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your logic is backwards, you want to show the img tag when there IS a photo so you need to use `not empty` and probably only want to check if you have a photo id

```
<c:if test="not empty ${statusUpdate.photo.id}">  
        <img class="img-responsive full-width" src="${contextRoot}/statusphoto/${statusUpdate.photo.id}" alt=""/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it shows none. I think the problem is on the test... it may be something different to an empty or not empty test. Thanks for you help, anyway.

Comment: But it works with <c:if test="${statusUpdate.photo != null}">               <img class="img-responsive full-width" src="${contextRoot}/statusphoto/${statusUpdate.photo.id}" alt=""/>
     </c:if>